# Is there anything like Telephony.SECRET_CODE in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone

Is there anything like Telephony.SECRET_CODE in iOS? I need to open my application if international numbers are typed on phone dial pad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what Telephony.SECRET_CODE is but you can't open an iOS app from the phone app.

Comment: telephony secret code is code used in android by which we can open app by typing some code in dial pad.